# How to combine proxy and basic auth in Apache

Tags: apache, buildbot

How do you combine basic auth with a reverse proxy in Apache?

I have an Apache site currently configured to use basic auth with an htpasswd file using this config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    # Requires: a2enmod proxy_http
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8010/

    <Location />
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Sensitive"
        AuthUserFile /usr/local/myproject/htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

Apache is acting as a wrapper around a Buildbot server being served on port `:8010`. However, this app has been upgraded so it now requires the use of websockets. The suggested [Apache configuration](http://docs.buildbot.net/latest/manual/cfg-www.html#reverse-proxy-configuration) is:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    <Location /ws>
      ProxyPass ws://127.0.0.1:8010/ws
      ProxyPassReverse ws://127.0.0.1:8010/ws
    </Location>

    ProxyPass /ws !
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8010/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8010/

</VirtualHost>
```

However, this doesn't use any authentication. I tried re-adding my `<Location />` section from the previous config, so I now have:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    <Location />
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Sensitive"
        AuthUserFile /usr/local/myproject/htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>

    <Location /ws>
      ProxyPass ws://127.0.0.1:8010/ws
      ProxyPassReverse ws://127.0.0.1:8010/ws
    </Location>

    ProxyPass /ws !
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8010/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8010/

</VirtualHost>
```

and although Apache now correctly prompts for my username+password, the Buildbot still isn't given authenticated username and still renders for an anonymous user.

How do I fix this config to pass the username (I believe the `REMOTE_USER` header) through to the web app behind the reverse proxy?